# Delete 200 items at a time from a list

Tags: list

I was trying to figure out how can i delete more than 200 items at a time from list in SharePoint 2010. I can change the view limit and delete 100 items but its pain to delete from both SharePoint list as well from recycle bin . Is there a easy way to delete the huge number of items from list using jquery or javascript . Since we are not suppose to use VS solutions in our environment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you use the powershell?

Comment: Hi waqas no i cannot use but may be farm administrator can use. But i am looking something specific to client side .But could you provide here how can we do with PS script which helps in case anyone with javascript doesn't reply. I can give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this blog](http://matthewyarlett.blogspot.com/2013/07/well-that-was-fun-bulk-deleting-items.html)

Create the query:

```
$list =  (Get-Spweb http://devmy101).GetList("http://devmy101/Lists/smarEnteredTerritorialWaters")
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery;
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
$query.RowLimit = 2000;
$query.Query = '<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name="Created"/><Value Type="DateTime" IncludeTimeValue="TRUE">2013-07-10T14:20:00Z</Value></Gt></Where>';
```

Build the command (note the query is limited to returning 2000 items at a time, and uses the ListItemCollectionPosition property to continue retrieving items in batches of 2000 until all the items have been queried. See this MSDN documentation for more info.)

```
$itemCount = 0;
$listId = $list.ID;
[System.Text.StringBuilder]$batchXml = New-Object "System.Text.StringBuilder";
$batchXml.Append("<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"UTF-8`"?><Batch>");
$command = [System.String]::Format( "<Method><SetList>{0}</SetList><SetVar Name=`"ID`">{1}</SetVar><SetVar Name=`"Cmd`">Delete</SetVar></Method>", $listId, "{0}" );

do
{
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    foreach ($item in $listItems)
    {
        if($item -ne $null){$batchXml.Append([System.String]::Format($command, $item.ID.ToString())) | Out-Null;$itemCount++;}
    }
}
while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

$batchXml.Append("</Batch>");
$itemCount;
```

And lastly (and most importantly!), run the query

```
$web = Get-Spweb http://inceweb/HKMarineDB;
$web.ProcessBatchData($batchXml.ToString()) | Out-Null;
```

Comment: thank you waqar do you have any idea on how to do same using jquery or java script? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to bulk delete in Javascript.

```
var context = null;
var web = null;
function deleteAllItems()
{
    var okToContinue = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all items in this list?");

if(okToContinue)
{
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    context.load(web);
    var ID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    curList = web.get_lists().getById(ID);
    context.load(curList);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID' />  <Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query></View>");
    this.collListItem = curList.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(collListItem);

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate
    (this, this.onSuccessGetList, Function.createDelegate,
    this, this.onFailure));
    }
}

function onSuccessGetList(sender, args)
{
    var listItemEnum = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    var counter = 0;
    var itemArr = new Array();

    while(listItemEnum.moveNext())
    {
        var listItem = listItemEnum.get_current();
        itemArr[counter] = listItem.get_item("ID");
        counter++;
    }
    for(var id in itemArr)
    {
        var spItem = curList.getItemById(itemArr[id]);
        spItem.deleteObject();
    } 
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate
    (this, this.onSuccessClean, Function.createDelegate,
    this, this.onFailure));
    }
    function onSuccessClean(sender, args)
    {
        alert("All items deleted!");
        window.location = window.location.href;
    }
    function onFailure(sender, args)
    { 
        alert("Error");
    }
```

The above code belongs to this blog [post](http://nikcharlebois.sharepointspace.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=12dd66b5-8904-4234-bb9c-28760c5460ca&ID=21&Web=3ace3513-f713-47a3-ad5a-7d0ab95015a5) where the function is getting used in a ribbon to delete all items in a SharePoint List.

Comment: hi rakib after looking in to the link it shows there used visual studio and inserting this code in master page. Can i use this script in content editor web part or some how to delete the list items ?

Comment: You can certainly use this in content editor web part but I would suggest to use it in a separate JS file and add a reference to that file in the master page.